# WebLogic deploy error

Tags: java, oracle, ssl, weblogic, middleware

We are using WebLogic version 11g to deploy our application. Previously the Java version we were using was 1.6, then upgraded to Java 1.7,

After upgradation on trying to start managed server weblogic console is showing error on the top:

> The Node Manager associated with machine is not reachable.

On the node manager window below exception is coming:

```
<WARNING> <Uncaught exception in server handlerjavax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: FATAL Alert:PROTOCOL_VERSION - The protocol version requested is recognized but not supported.>
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: FATAL Alert:PROTOCOL_VERSION - The protocol version requested is recognized but not supported.
```

We tried looking at various posts and tried some solutions like adding some flag on manager server start but none of them worked.

Comment: could you clarify what solutions and what flags you've tried? and what happened when you did? Please add that to the question.

Comment: @eis Like we added this flag -Dweblogic.security.SSL.enforceConstraints=off on managed server startup. We got this solution from following post. https://community.oracle.com/thread/1063277?start=0

Comment: did you try to specify that to node manager? how about suggested `-Dssl.debug=true`? any logs on that?

Comment: @eis I was not aware we can do the same for node manager also. Where to set this property -Dssl.debug=true

Comment: the same place where you specified `-Dweblogic.security.SSL.enforceConstraints=off`

Comment: @eris we logged in to the domain console and under the managed server SSL argument properties we have added this flag. For Node Manager there is no as such login system. So any particular file where we need to do this?? Thanks in advance

Comment: that depends your operating system and how you've defined the node manager to start. Possibly you need to add it to the startup script. You didn't yet add ssl.debug=true output to the question, please do so.